# Issue: Glib-Gobject-warning **: cannot register existing type 'GDKDisplayManager'

Tags: opencv, gui

I've designed a interface with pyqt and python to my raspberry, so there's no problem when I run a basic test to open the camera  ( cv2.imshow('test',frame) this is too basic is just to check if my camera is working) and yeah the camera open successfully but the problem occurs when I try to open the camera within my interface created on pyqt5, because it launches a few errors but the main is 
   `Glib-Gobject-Warning **: cannot register existing type 'GDKDisplayManager'`

Full Error:

```
Glib-Gobject-Warning **: cannot register existing type 'GDKDisplayManager'
Glib-critical **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0 ' failed
Glib-Gobject-CRITICAL **:g_object_new: assertion 'G_TyPE_IS_OBJECT(Object_type)'fail
Glib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (null) pointer instance
Glib-GObject-CRTICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE(instance)'failed
Glib_GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GdkDisplay'
Glib-critical **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0 ' failed
Glib-Gobject-CRITICAL **: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_Type > 0'failed
Glib-critical **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0 ' failed
Glib-Gobject-CRITICAL **:g_object_new: assertion 'G_TyPE_IS_OBJECT(Object_type)'failed
```

This is the function which is opening the camera

```
    def OpenCamera(self):
    self.setup_CameraSettings()       
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.CameraSource) # video capture source camera (Here webcam of laptop) 
    cap.set(3, self.Resolution_x) # set the resolution
    cap.set(4, self.Resolution_y)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTOFOCUS, 0) # turn the autofocus off
    focus = self.Focus  # min: 0, max: 255, increment:5
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOCUS, focus)

    ret,frame = cap.read() # return a single frame in variable `frame`

    if ret== True:            
        cv2.imshow('Settings Test',frame)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows() 
    else:
        self.popUp_Message('Camera Unplugged')
```

This code is running successfully on my PC so the problem is not in the function, I think is about PyQt at my raspberry pi